# How to create HTML reports using Jmeter Maven Plugin 2.1.0.

Tags: maven, jmeter-maven-plugin

Jmeter Maven plugin 1.4 used to generate nice HTML reports but the latest plugin 2.1.0 does not create. I know for the latest plugin by default enableReports are set to false.

I would like to know how HTML reports can be enabled without usage of any other plugin in pom.xml?

or

which plugin is compatible with Jmeter Maven plugin 2.1.0 which can be used to generate HTML reports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this to working? I tried the solution below and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

the HTML reports in 1.4 were removed because they were horrifically inefficient.

In version 2.6.0 of the plugin you can use JMeter's native report generation, just add in a config setting of:

```
<configuration>
    <generateReports>true</generateReports>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Bravo, Bravo, sir!   Using Jmeter maven plugin 2.9.0 (latest),  this option for creating a report is by far the best .   I didn't know about this.  There is soooo much misinformation on the internet about how to make a Jmeter report in Maven.   I thank you sir!