# Apache Dashboard HTML reports with Jmeter Maven plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want `mvn clean verify` to run following command for me

`jmeter -n  -t <file.jmx> -l <reports.csv> -e -o /htmlReports`

I checked below similar question [How to create HTML reports using Jmeter Maven Plugin 2.1.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601944/how-to-create-html-reports-using-jmeter-maven-plugin-2-1-0)  but it didn't work for me.

I want all data to be inside `target` folder, plus `.jtl` so that at next run all previous gets cleaned up.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.performancetesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo-performance-testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
                <configuration>

                        <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                    </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/*.jtl</inputFile>
                    <graphs>
                        <graph>
                            <pluginType>ResponseTimesOverTime</pluginType>
                            <width>800</width>
                            <height>600</height>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/BlazeDemoRequest.png</outputFile>
                        </graph>
                    </graphs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Maven Exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), the relevant configuration would be

```
<configuration>
    <basedir>/path/to/bin/folder/of/your/jmeter/installation</basedir>
    <executable>jmeter</executable>
    <commandlineArgs>-n -t -f file.jmx -l ${basedir}/target/reports.csv -e -o ${basedir}/target/htmlReports</commandlineArgs>
</configuration>
```

Just in case something "will not work" again here is full *pom.xml* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <basedir>/path/to/bin/folder/of/your/jmeter/installation</basedir>
                            <executable>jmeter</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>-n -t -f file.jmx -l ${basedir}/target/reports.csv -e -o
                                ${basedir}/target/htmlReports
                            </commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Don't forget to change `/path/to/bin/folder/of/your/jmeter/installation` to real path to your JMeter** otherwise it "will not work".

---

Report generation via [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) should also work fine, if you experience any issues please show your *pom.xml* file and maven command output.

Example configuration you can use for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

N.B.

- you will need to copy your file.jmx script into src/test/jmeter folder, otherwise it "will not work"
- if your test is using any [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - it "will not work" without [defining them as dependencies](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)
- if your test uses external data files - it "will not work" unless you copy them to src/test/jmeter folder

More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Hey,  Pretty detailed answer. Two things aren't clear `1.` How can I still manage to get jtl file? `2.` Reports get generated using second `pom.xml` and first are identical?

Comment: In case of JMeter Maven plugin you will have the .jtl file(s) under `target/jmeter/results` folder. Reports should be identical given you have the same JMeter configuration in both cases

Comment: It failed the build due to MojoExceptionError. I have attached pom and `-e` error stack in the question descriptiopn.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve? Why do you want to run your test twice? If you want to use maven plugin - go for `<configuration><generateReports>true</generateReports></configuration>` like in my latter sample. If you want to run your test using [command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) - go for my first sample. The mix of two approaches doesn't make sense

Comment: You are saying that I am using configuration tags both in Jmeter maven plugin and in `exec` plugin. You are right? I have removed mojo configuration and set `true` to the value of `<generateReports>` under `<configuration>` tag of  `jmeter maven plugin` (Updated the `pom.xml` in question). This time tests ran but didnt generate the html reports, `jtl` only `csv` files in `target/jmeter/results` folder.

Comment: Here are jmeter logs https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f4DXLLyJr7bVRgDj37kiZNaoxQdXq_eAjU1cTijIRWU/edit

Answer (score 0):

Report generation with [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Basic-Configuration) works for your requirement, you don't need any additional plugin.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.performancetesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo-performance-testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Requirements:

- copy your jmx file into src/test/jmeter folder
- if you use 3rd party plugins like [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), ensure you follow this [documentation](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)
- if you use CSV data files - copy them to src/test/jmeter folder

Comment: It is only generating 1 `jtl` file and 1 `csv` file, nothing else inside the `target/jmeter/results` folder. If you are right then whats the use of `<generateReports>true</generateReports>`? This tag is missing in your `pom.xml`

Comment: Hello, it is working for me, generatereports is true by default, if you don’t need them you set it to false and format to xml. For your information, we are committers on jmeter maven plugin. Did you look into all content of target folder?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Create test plan and save JMX script

Step 2 - Executing JMeter tests

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>jmeter-tests</id>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>jmeter</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
     <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Step 3 - Save test result into csv/xls file

Step 4 - The following plugin is used to transform the result

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>transform</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <transformationSets>
      <transformationSet>
       <dir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results</dir>
       <stylesheet>${project.basedir}/src/main/jmeter-results-report_21.xsl</stylesheet>
       <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results</outputDir>
       <fileMappers>
        <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.RegExpFileMapper">
         <pattern>(.*?)\s(.*?)</pattern>
         <replacement>$1$2</replacement>
         <replaceAll>true</replaceAll>
        </fileMapper>
        <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
         <targetExtension>.html</targetExtension>
        </fileMapper>
       </fileMappers>
      </transformationSet>
     </transformationSets>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```